# Naming PCB connector metal socket in plastic housing

Tags: socket, crimp

What is this PCB connector type?

From the array of unsoldered connectors in plastic housing the metal socket is supposed to be replaced. Pictures present missing metal socket yet its type/name is unknown to me.
[image: Metal socket missing here]
[image: This socket is replaced]
*Does anyone have this part's name?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the wire cage of a terminal block. I don't believe I've ever seen them sold separately. I recommend replacing the entire terminal block, preferably with one where the cage doesn't fall out if the screw is backed out too far.